# HTML 5 <Video> markup not working with iPhone, but works with Safari / iPad

Tags: html, html5-video

`<video controls="controls" width="720" height="406">
  <source src="test/kws.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`

Any reason this markup doesn't work with iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the codecs part? If no codecs are specified, they will be autodetected.

Also, did you use the baseline format for the encoding? The iPhone does not support any part of h.264 other than baseline.

Comment: That's not the issue. I added it in just to try and correct what ever possible. However, I decided to just convert it to a link instead of using the Video tag when it detects iphone. It works like a charm.